# Update the clickable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a click event on a replaced element.

```
var checks_int = "1";
$(function () {
    var plus = $('.fa-plus');

    plus.click(function () {
        if (checks_int <= 5) {
            $(this).parent().parent().append("<li><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></li>");
            $(this).parent().html("").html("<i class='fa fa-check' check='"+ (checks_int + 1) +"'></i><p><input name='check1' type='text' placeholder='Check'></p>");
            checks_int++;
            if (checks_int > 5) {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            }
        }
        plus = $('.fa-plus');
    });
});
```

All of this is working fine, but only the first try, when I click the "new" `.fa .fa-check` nothing happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your click handler to the one shown below. That should do it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-plus', function() {
    ......... your code here ..............
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on function http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
var checks_int = 1;

$('body').on('click', '.fa-plus', function(){
if (checks_int <= 5) {
        $(this).parent().parent().append("<li><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></li>");
        $(this).parent().html("").html("<i class='fa fa-check' check='"+ (checks_int + 1) +"'></i><p><input name='check1' type='text' placeholder='Check'></p>");
        checks_int++;
        if (checks_int > 5) {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: with $('body') it doesent work Oo but with document already. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You cloud actually have a container div and select it `<div id="container"><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></div>` `$('#container')`